# Google Apps Script that hides row if a date is less than or equal to today's date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

In Google Sheets, I have a tab titled "Scheduled" that has all our client's import dates. I need to automatically hide (NOT delete) rows on that tab if the import date (column D) is less than or equal to the current date. Basically, automate right-clicking on the row and selecting "Hide Row" based on the parameters listed above.

Completely new to Google Apps Script so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please attach (a copy of) the Google Sheet.

Comment: Here you go! I had to remove some formulas and links for privacy but the data is there so should be all you need.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mvMbHWugISALRnczojiEZzxQFnFLiPLC-w9T-7rU918/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: @taylor.2317 Consider asking for tables instead of shared sheets file.

Comment: @TheMaster apologies

Comment: @taylor.2317 It is just a suggestion and not a rule. No need to apologize.

Answer (score 0):

```
=$D1<edate(today(),6)
```

5 Steps:

1. Select the cell, cell `D1`
2. Go to Format, Conditional Formatting
   [image: Fig.1]
3. Under Format Rules, scroll to the bottom of the drop-down list to find "Custom Formula is"
   [image: Fig.2]
4. In the text input box, copy and paste the code above
5. Change the text and background colours to white. To change the colour, use the Formatting options
   [image: Fig.3]

**Please note: when changing cell, change the code `D1` to the *current* cell.**

Comment: This does not work. All it does is make the whole row white. I need to hide the entire row so there are no blank rows in between other rows. This is why I need a script as it cannot be done with conditional formatting. But, thank you for trying!

Comment: Ok - apologies: I did not understand the original question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hide old rows

```
function hideOldRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sr = 2; //data start row
  const dv = new Date().valueOf();
  sh.getRange(sr,4,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat().map((d,i) => [new Date(d).valueOf(),i+sr]).filter(r => r[0] < dv).forEach(r => sh.hideRows(r[1]));
}
```

Sheet0 before:

[image]

Sheet0 After:

[image]

Comment: Hi Cooper, so I adjusted the sheet name to 'Scheduled' but didn't touch anything else. Added the script and saved it but nothing is happening. is there something I need to do to trigger the script to run?

Comment: You need to run it

Comment: I tested the code and it runs for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your script editor:

```
function hideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Scheduled"); //get Scheduled sheet
  var dateRange = sh.getRange(2, 4, sh.getLastRow()-1, 1); //get column D range
  var dates = dateRange.getDisplayValues(); //get the values of column D using the range fetched above
  var currentDate = new Date(); //get current date

  for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
    var date = new Date(dates[i][0].replace(/-/g, '\/').replace(/T.+/, '')); //convert column D values to date
    if(date.valueOf() <= currentDate.valueOf()){  // check if the date is less than or equal to current date
      sh.hideRows(i+2); // hide row
    }
  }
  
}
```

**Test Data:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [Date.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)
- [Sheet.hideRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex)